# How to combine column in dataframe based on date&time and take the mean of the value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I would like to ask how can I join the dataframe as shown in (exiting dataframe) to group values based on date&time and take the means of the values. what I meant is that if col B have 2 values in the same minute , it will take average of that value and do same for rest of the columns. What I want to achieve is to have one value each minutes as shown in (preprocessed dataframe)

Thank you

[image: Existing Dataframe]

[image: Preprocessed Dataframe]

Comment: refer to guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and  post data as a code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is called df, you can do as following :

```
df.groupby(['DataTime']).mean()
```